# psuedo-op error in assembly language

Tags: macos, assembly, macports, gnu-assembler

I' new to assembly language and my computer's assembler seems to be unable to assemble ever since I upgraded to macOs Sierra. My assembly code is written under the Intel architecture with the AT&T syntax on my macbook pro. I have been using the OS X assembler from Terminal with the "as" command. The code assembled fine before the update but afterwards I keep getting psuedo-op errors for all the .cfi directives and the .macosx_version_min directive. I've also tried testing out new assembly code by creating them from simple c++ code by using the "gcc -S" and "g++ -S" commands in Terminal. However, the assembler now gives the same errors for this test assembly code. Here is the c++ test code:

```
int main()
{ return 7; }
```

The assembly code generated by the command " g++ -S Sample_1.cpp -o Sample_1.s":

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 12
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    $7, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

and the output from Terminal after running the command "as Sample_1.s -o Sample_1.o:

```
Sample_1.s:2:Unknown pseudo-op: .macosx_version_min
Sample_1.s:2:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
Sample_1.s:6:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_startproc
Sample_1.s:10:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_def_cfa_offset
Sample_1.s:10:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
Sample_1.s:12:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_offset
Sample_1.s:12:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 37 (%).
Sample_1.s:15:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_def_cfa_register
Sample_1.s:15:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 37 (%).
Sample_1.s:20:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_endproc
```

Can anyone can tell me how to fix these errors or why these errors are happening? Thanks and have a great day.

Edit: @Jester I can compile with gcc directly. The output from the "-v" command is:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name Sample_1.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 274.1 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/User/Documents/Programs/Sample/Assembly -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -o /var/folders/df/xf35rr653qb6kyyrf7bpsw180000gn/T/Sample_1-cae459.o -x c++ Sample_1.cpp
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o Sample_1 /var/folders/df/xf35rr653qb6kyyrf7bpsw180000gn/T/Sample_1-cae459.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

2nd Edit: Ok I've figured out the problem. Btw thanks @Jester for all your help. It turns out MacPorts decided to rewrite the path of the "as" command to its own assembler (the GNU assembler instead of the OS X assembler), which is unable to understand the lldb debugging .cfi directives. By editing the changes MacPorts made to my .bash_profile, the code assembled normally.

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade your assembler. Can you compile program with gcc directly? Then maybe you have multiple versions of the assembler installed and you invoked the wrong one. In that case let gcc invoke the assembler for you and also use `-v` switch so you can see what it does.

Comment: Can you try `llvm-as` instead of `as`?

Comment: @hidefromkgb, Terminal gives a "command not found" error to llvm-as

Comment: What happens if you do `gcc Sample_1.s -o Sample_1.o`?

Comment: @Jester "gcc Sample_1.s -o Sample_1.o" compiles fine with no errors

Comment: There you go, you can use that to assemble. You could try adding `-v` to that command too.